# Drop shadow for FrameLayout programmatically

Tags: android, xml, layout, frame, shadow

Is there a way to add a `drop shadow` to a `FrameLayout` programmatically without the use of an additional XML file?

If yes please can you provide me a solution?

Something like that:

[image]

Comment: Why do not added any drop shadow image in FrameLayout background programmatically?.

Comment: I don't want to do a different image everytime I need to change the background color @MdAbdulGafur

Comment: post an image describing how it should look like

Comment: make a custom FrameLayout and override its dispatchDraw method

Comment: can you explain a bit more? @pskink

Comment: create a class like this: class ShadowFrameLayout extends FrameLayout { ... and override dispatchDraw(Canvas) method, make sure you call super.dispatchDraw and then add your shadow drawing code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by creating a gradient color on Photoshop, then creating views that has this color as background. On transitions, I change the X,Y,width,height properly :)

Edit 2019:

The simple solution now is add some elevation to the FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the shadow drawable in [Google IO 2014 App](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/DrawShadowFrameLayout.java)